# C code Optimization by compiler for atmel studio

Tags: gcc, avr, avr-gcc, avr-studio7

I am using Atmel Studio 7 and in that, optimization level is -O1.
Can I check what portion of code is being optimized by the compiler itself?
If I am disabling the optimization, my binary file size is of 12KB and on using optimization level -O1, binary file size if 5.5KB.

Comment: Just check the generated machine code. Since it's GCC, you don't have to disassemble but you can simply tell the compiler to output assembler code instead of machine code.

Comment: Check .lss file among output files. It's generating should be enabled by default, if not, enable it in project options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I check what portion of code is being optimized by the compiler itself?

*All* the code is optimized by the compiler, i.e affected by optimization flags except

1. It's code that's dragged from libraries (`libgcc.a`, `libc.a`, `libm.a`, `lib<device>.a`).
2. Startup code (`crt<device>.o`) which also includes the vector table, or code from other objects that already exist and are not (re-)compiled in the current compilation.  The latter can happen with Makefiles when you change flags therein:  If the modules do not depend on the Makefile itself, `make` will not rebuild them.
3. Code from assembly modules (`*.S`, `*.sx`, `*.s`) provided preprocessed assembly code does not use conditional assemblation by means of `#ifdef  __OPTIMIZE__` or similar.
4. Code in inline assembly, provided the inline asm is not optimized away.

In order to determine whether anything of this is in effect, you can respectively:

1. Link with `-Wl,-Map,file.map` and inspect that map file (a text file).  It will list which objects have been dragged from where due to which undefined symbol.
2. Startup code is linked except you `-nostartfiles`.  Add `-Wl,-v` to the link stage, you'll see `crt<device>.o` being linked.
3. You know your compilation units, assembly modules, don't you?
4. Add `-save-temps` to the compilation.  Inline asm will show in the intermediate `*.s` file as

   ```
   /* #APP */
   ;  <line> "<compilation-unit>"
       <inline-asm-code>
   /* #NOAPP */
   ```